# whom was the radio invented by?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

Is the following question correct? I want this style of questioning not alternatives.

> who or whom was the radio invented by?
>   by who was the radio invented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whom is a word that is dying out. If you look up "by whom" in Google ngrams you will see that its use has been declining steadily since the early 19th century. If you want to use it, the correct formulation would be "by whom was the radio invented", but if you actually said those words you would risk being laughed at because they sound very old-fashioned. Being a bit old-fashioned myself I do use "to whom" occasionally as in "to whom did you give the book?", but even I would not use "by whom" other than in jest.

If you really want to know the name of the inventor, the clearest way to ask is in the active not the passive voice:"who invented the radio?"

Comment: so you mean: who did you give the book to? who killed bruce lee? instead of by whom was bruce lee killed (in an exam for example? ) by whom was north korea knocked down?

Comment: "_by whom was bruce lee killed_" sound very awkward.

Comment: @SirMeysamFerguson Passive constructions are usually avoided unless there is a good reason for them. There is really no good reason for them in a simple question like this. So I'll reiterate what JeremyC says: it's best to say, "Who invented the radio?" or "Who was the inventor of the radio?"

Comment: I don't think **whom** has reached the to-be-laughed-at stage yet.

Comment: It has where I come from (Cambridgeshire, UK), I regret to say, especially when used with "by".

Comment: Where I come from (Philadelphia PA) we would say *Who ya goin'  to the dance with?*    and *That was said by who?*  But **by whom** is alive and well in many kinds of writing.

Comment: Yes, it is alive. But I was referring to spoken English.